# Djangoでローカライズが反映されない

Tags: django

[[Python] Django ロケールファイルを追加して日本語メッセージを変更する - Qiita](https://qiita.com/okoppe8/items/e1c8d4b6ba24af788504)
などを参考に、英語を元文にして日本語ユーザーには日本語で表示するように開発したはずなのですが、英語で表示されてしまいます。もちろんブラウザの言語設定は日本語にしています。

試しにsettings.pyのLANGUAGE_CODEを'en-us'から'ja'にしたらちゃんと日本語が表示されるようになったのでソースなどは間違ってないはずです。しかしこれだと海外ユーザーにも日本語で表示されてしまうと思うので、LANGUAGE_CODEを'en-US'のままローカライズしたいと思います。
どのすれば解決するでしょう？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ミドルウェアを追加してないことが原因でした。失礼しました。
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',#これ
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
参考リンク：[Django、多言語対応 - Narito Blog](https://narito.ninja/blog/detail/86/)